# Access a directory with hidden hashbangs

Tags: angularjs

I am using the routing feature of angularjs for my website and the html5mode(true) to hide the hashbang on the url, now i had a simple problem i want to access a directory(Access/) quitting from routing if i write directly "www.example.com/Access" on the url obviously it will redirect to the redirectTo website present on script file.

I want to access this directory with a new file and not via the ng-view.

My routing controller:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$routeProvider.when('/'+PAGINE.Home,{templateUrl:'pagine/Pagina_iniziale.html',controller:'Pagina_iniziale'})
.when('/'+PAGINE.Social,{templateUrl:'pagine/Social_news.html'})
.when('/'+PAGINE.Catalogo,{templateUrl:'pagine/Catalogo.html'})
.when('/'+PAGINE.Partner,{templateUrl:'pagine/Partner.html'})
.when('/'+PAGINE.Faq,{templateUrl:'pagine/Faq.html'})
.when('/'+PAGINE.Contatti,{templateUrl:'pagine/Contatti.html'})
.otherwise({redirectTo:'/'+PAGINE.Home});
```

How i can access the Access page quitting from routing?